# Azure function can not access key vault within VNET- Public network access is disabled

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, vnet

I have a function app that is integrated with a Vnet (with a single subnet). I also have two service endpoints in the same subnet for a storage account and key vault.

The storage account is accessed with a key and works on the vnet without issue.

The key vault has an access policy specified to give the function app managed identity access to list and get secrets. When I fetch a secret from the vault, I get the following message:

"Public network access is disabled and request is not from a trusted service nor via an approved private link."

Function app -> Vnet -> service endpoints (Storage / Vault)

|-> Uses Storage Key - OK

|-> Uses Vault and managed identity -> "Public network access is disabled ..."

Function app is in the Vnet. Do I need additional routing?

Please advice as I am stumped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the vault with the exact same settings and it worked as expected. Very weird. Something must have broken in the Vault configuration with regards to the Firewall routing.